# Why the data is going as null in my test and how to convert it data provider data as per my function in java

Tags: java

I have read some data from Excel in array form, and converted into a 2-D array in order to provide the data to a data provider.But now in the @Test when I pass the data it takes on the null value.

Can you please suggest why it's going null? Also my function in @Test is using a map as well - how can I convert the data provider data to map ?

My function in @Test is like below:-

```
public void testCategorySearch(String vendor_code, Map<Integer, List<String>> seller_sku , String upload_id,Protocol protocol)
            throws InvocationTargetException
```

My code is :

```
@DataProvider(name = "valid_parameters")
public Object[][] sendValidParameters() {
    List<ArrayList> result = td.getExcelData("C:\\Users\\ashish.gupta02\\QAAutomation\\test.xls", 1);
    Object[][] a = new String[result.size()][3];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Object currentObject = result.get(i);
            a[i][0] = currentObject.toString();
            System.out.println("COnverted" + a[i][0]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Printing data" + a);
    //return  mapper.getProtocolMappedObject(a);

    //return Object ;
    return  a;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "valid_parameters", groups = {"positive"})
public void testCategorySearch(String vendor_code, Map<Integer, List<String>> seller_sku, String upload_id, Protocol protocol)
        throws InvocationTargetException {
    //Protocol protocol
    //set parameter values to the api
    System.out.println("Executing the request");

    CreateSellerProductUpdateInfoRequest createReq = setRequest(vendor_code, seller_sku, upload_id, protocol);

    CreateSellerProductUpdateInfoResponse createResponse = service.createSellerProductUpdateInfo(createReq);

    System.out.print("Response is :" + createResponse);
}
```

Comment: May I assume you are using junit? (You have not included the imports, so I just guess.) Probably you are using it with the `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`. The reason you are seeing `null`s, is because you forget to compute the second and third parameter objects (also the fourth, but there you do not even have space in the output array). Complete your provider and it should just work.

Comment: I am providing data to @data provider from excel.My content in excel is like :upload_id vendor_code seller_sku Category_id
       UID123 aace21          sku1           1
So when i debug it , i found that my a[i][0] is providing { UID123 aace21          sku1           1}...So how can i provide [i] [1] i.e 2nd and 3rd parameter objects.